# How to Update Elevated Button title on Pressed in Particular index of ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

Here is my code.

```
bool isAddedToCart = false;
return ListView.builder(
........
 ElevatedButton (
                        child: isAddedToCart? Text('Added to cart') : Text('Add to cart'),
                         style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                           primary: Constants.primaryColor,
                           onPrimary: Constants.appColor
                         ),
                         onPressed: () async{
                           setState(() {
                             isAddedToCart = !isAddedToCart;
                           });
                           
                         },
                      
                       ),
```

The problem is, if I click on that elevated Button the text of that button has to change on that index only. But it is changing in all the index which are in listview.builder.

Can any one have a solution for this that only one button on selected index has to update with changed name.

Comment: Make sure to use a Stateful widget. And instead of working with a single boolean variable you should have a List of strings and index it with the ListView builder index.

Comment: yes, am using stateFulWidget.

Comment: It obviously is a logical error. You have to create a flag for each index of the list. And check if the flag is true (added to cart) or false (not added to cart).

In this case, all you are doing is updating the title of all the buttons in your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All items were depends on `isAddedToCart`  but You need to store the selected item with separate indexing

```
List<int> _selected_item = List();

 ElevatedButton(
              child: _selected_item.contains(index)
                  ? Text('Added to cart')
                  : Text('Add to cart'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  // remove or add index to _selected_item
                  if (_selected_item.contains(index))
                    _selected_item.remove(index);
                  else
                    _selected_item.add(index);
                  print(index);
                });
              },
            )
```

complete source code

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              child: _selected_item.contains(index)
                  ? Text('Added to cart')
                  : Text('Add to cart'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(),
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  // remove or add index to _selected_item
                  if (_selected_item.contains(index))
                    _selected_item.remove(index);
                  else
                    _selected_item.add(index);
                  print(index);
                });
              },
            );
          })
```

Comment: @GH you can try out this I hope, it will work for you

Comment: that was super. thankyou.

Comment: it was getting to default when it is reloading. Can we do it using model, if yes, how?

Comment: you should follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57380673/dynamically-created-checkbox-in-flutter-not-changing-the-state-on-clicked

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep the flag `isAddedToCart` for each index. You can achieve it by using a `Map`. Something like this:

```
// class variable scope.
Map<int, bool> isAddedToCartMap = {};
```

then use it in your widget:

```
ElevatedButton (
    // if isAddedToCartMap[index] not found, use false as default value.
    child: isAddedToCartMap[index]??false ? Text('Added to cart') : Text('Add to cart'),
     style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       primary: Constants.primaryColor,
       onPrimary: Constants.appColor
     ),
     onPressed: () async{
       setState(() {
         isAddedToCartMap[index] = !isAddedToCartMap[index]??false;
       });
       
     },
  
   ),
```

Comment: its working fine, i have a dout.. How to update the same button to 'Add to cart' again. thanks for reply @ישו אוהב אותך